# What are the significant assumption of the Inflation Theory?

Tags: cosmological-inflation

Can it still be considered theory ?, because I can't find it's major or significant assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most significant assumption is that very shortly after the Big Bang, the universe expanded very rapidly for a short period of time. Much faster than normal expansion due to Big Bang. It was an exponential expansion and occurred around ${10}^{-32}$ seconds after Big Bang and lasted for tiny fraction of second. The universe continues to expand but not at that exponential rate. Yes it is still a theory and is accepted by many scientists.

Comment: Oh, Thank you for clearing things up and forgive me for my ignorance

Comment: Nothing ignorant about not knowing that.  you had sense enough to ask.  Most people think of the inflationary universe just as the the expanding universe with no idea of the brief exponential expansion.